# Calc how many times a word appears in a text file with bash

Tags: bash

So I have a file that's being generated by another tool. I want to process this file and calculate how many times a word appears in the file. Kinda like a word map to get the tone of the file.

This is what I have so far but for some reason I keep getting just the words and not a count of the words
`cat words.txt | tr -s ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq | sort -nr | awk '{print $2 " " $1}'`

so for example, if I have `test test test` in the file, I just get `test` as my output when in reality I want to see `test 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass by `uniq` you are losing the count of each word because uniq strips out the repetition count by default.

You have to use `uniq -c` which means 'count' option.